# necesito ayuda con socket.io y node.js

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

//Soy nuevo en socket y node, recien estoy empezando, estoy tratando de hacer una sala de chat

```
const socket = io();

let mensaje = document.getElementById('texto');
let btn = document.getElementById('enviar');
let mostrar = document.getElementById('recibir');

btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{

socket.emit('mensaje', {
    mensaje:mensaje.value
});

socket.on('mensaje', (data) =>{
    mostrar.innerHTML += '<p> ${data.mensaje} </p>'
   })
})
```

/este es el index.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//AJUSTE DE LOS PUERTOS 
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//CODIGO SIMPLE PARA ESCUCHAR EL PUERTO 
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>{
console.log('servidor en el puerto', app.get('port'));
})

 //RUTAS DE LOS ARCHIVOS ESTATICOS 
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


    //TODO LO QUE TENGA QUE VER CON SOCKET.IO 

  const SocketIO = require('socket.io');

  const io = SocketIO(server);

  io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  console.log('nueva conexion de socket', socket.id);

  socket.on('mensaje', (data) =>{

    io.sockets.emit('mensaje', data);
    })
  })
```

//este es el simpre codigo html, es corta ya que estoy haciendo practicas para porder ganar experiencia

```
    <div class="demo" id="recibir"></div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="mensaje" id="texto">
    <input type="submit" id="enviar">
</div>
```

//Mi problema es que cuando intento imprimir los datos enviados simplemente me aparece ${data.mensaje} y no lo que hay dentro de el objeto

Comment: Cambia las comillas simples ' por el ` en la linea mostrar.innerHTML += '<p> ${data.mensaje} </p>'